# GraphQL to query something other than ID

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, strapi

I am using [Strapi](https://strapi.io) with Nuxt.js to implement my first Headless CMS. I am using Apollo and GraphQL.

I am running into the current error and I've had no luck to figure this out for days.

If I write:

```
query Page($id: ID!) {
  page(id: $id) {
    id
    slug
    title
  }
}
```

And pass the following variable:

```
{
  "id" : "1"
}
```

I received the correct expected result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "page": {
      "id": "1",
      "slug": "/",
      "title": "Homepage"
    }
  }
}
```

HOWEVER, I would like to get the content not via ID, but via a field that I created in Strapi, called "slug".
Looking around, it seems like I should be able to do something like:

```
query Page($slug: String!) {
  page(slug: $slug) {
    id
    slug
    title
  }
}
```

With variable:

```
{
  "slug" : "/"
}
```

but I receive this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Unknown argument \"slug\" on field \"page\" of type \"Query\".",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 2,
            "column": 8
          }
        ],
        "extensions": {
          "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
          "exception": {
            "stacktrace": [
```

... the error continues....

[UPDATE] After Italo replied, I changed it into:

```
query Pages($slug: String!) {
  page(where: {slug: $slug}) {
    id
    slug
    title
  }
}
```

But I now get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Unknown argument \"where\" on field \"page\" of type \"Query\".",
```

I also noticed that I get a query if I change "page" into "pages", but it shows all of the pages...

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To query one item using something other than the primary key (and using just the default built-in queries from Strapi), you need to use the filters avaiable as a where clause:

```
query Pages($slug: String!) {
  pages(where: {slug: $slug}) {
    id
    slug
    title
  }
}
```

- Notice I'm using the endpoint Pages instead of Page, so this will
  return an array.
- Check the filters section here:
  https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/graphql.html#configurations

> Tip: use the Graphql interface avaiable in
>   http://localhost:1337/graphql to test that. (if you are not already)

Comment: Hi Italo, thanks for your reply.

Yes, I am using http://localhost:1337/graphql for testing, and making your changes, I now get the following error:

"message": "Unknown argument \"where\" on field \"page\" of type \"Query\".",

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. Just try changing `page(where:)` to `pages(where:)` (to be clear, you're supposed to use the query that find all pages instead of the one that returns just one item)

Comment: Just go to the graphql interface and use the autocompletition (ctrl+space) to check if the where field is avaiable.@Saro

Comment: Yeah, it works this way. However, I have to reference to it as pages[0].id or I get nothing. I do get the correct one by slug. 
It kind of feel wrong to me to have to use the [0], so I wonder if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: It's ok using this way and getting the record using pages[0], nothing wrong with it at all. But if you want to have something better, the only way is [creating a custom endpoint on graphql schema](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/graphql.html#customise-the-graphql-schema) It's not so hard and it's a good way to start tweeking strapi.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me using slug

create new file schema.graphql.js in
api/blog-post/config/schema.graphql.js

```
module.exports = {
  query: "blogPostBySlug(slug: String!): BlogPost",
  resolver: {
    Query: {
      blogPostBySlug: {
        description: "Return blog post with a given slug",
        resolver: "application::blog-post.blog-post.findOne",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

change routes.json in  api/blog-post/config/routes.json, from "path": "/blog-posts/:id" to "path": "/blog-posts/:slug:

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/blog-posts/:slug",
  "handler": "blog-post.findOne",
  "config": {
    "policies": []
  }
},
```

[image]